# Is there a way to create a button and a click event on this js function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

I've been trying for more than a day to make three implementations in this code, but still without success.

**1°** I need to create a button inside this page.

I've already tried to create a very normal button through html and css, but the fireworks page covers and hides the button element.
All elements displayed on the page are purely created within the JS file.

Here are the html and css

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="fireworksidButton" href="#" class="myButton">Click here</canvas>

<canvas id="firework"></canvas>

<canvas id="city"></canvas>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }

  canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  #app {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

.myButton {
    background-color:#44c767;
    border-radius:28px;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:28px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

**2°** I need to remove the Loop generated by the function.

I've already tried disabling this render action, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Here is the part of the script that  renders the loop action.

```
    let _pre = OrbitCalculator.pre_render();
    (function loop(count) {
      if (render_end) {
        render_end = false;
        _pre = OrbitCalculator.pre_render();
        loop(0);
        return;
      }

      if (count === MAX_AMOUNT_OF_FIREWORKS) {
        count--;
      } else {
        fireworks.push(_pre[count]);
      }

      setTimeout(() => loop(++count), INTERVAL);
    })(0);
```

**3°** I need to create a click event so that when the button is clicked, the function will be executed.

I´d like wrappe the function that triggers the Loop with the code below if it make sense.

```
function fireworksTrigger(){

document.querySelector('#fireworksidButton').addEventListener("click", async () => {

});
```

To make the function run, there is a dependence of the following library:
We can find the library inserted in the compiler´s settings.

[Library]https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.3.3/pixi.min.js

Here is the whole code running on the compiler. 599 Lines of code. That´s why i didn`t post the whole script here.

[Fireworks]https://codepen.io/paulodoporto/pen/Jjverod

What should I do please? Any Light?

**Thank you so much in advance!**

Comment: "*the fireworks page covers and hides the button*" - use `absolute` or `fixed` positioning and an increased `z-index`

Comment: @freedomn-m, I tried to use the code below, .myButton:active {position:absolute;z-index: 1000;top:1px;}. Now on the console I have the following error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null  at fireworks.js:10

Answer (score 0):

1. First i dont think that putting the button inside the canvas element is the best way to do it, you might just want to do `<button class='myButton'>Click here<button>`. To make the button not be covered by the canvas, i would suggest that you change the z-index like freedomn-m said. A higher z-index means that its placed higher when rendering, so make sure that the button has a higher z-index than the canvas. Alternatively, you can just put the button html after the canvas and that should automatically make the button on thop, since its rendered after.
2. I'm not 100% sure what your trying do do here but it looks like your using recursion so i would just use async and then sleep like this

```
    const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
    (async () => {
    /*whatever u wanna do*/ 
    await sleep(2);
    })();
```

3. You should just be able to put whatever function u wanna call inside the addeventlistener('click',//whatever') but this might not work unless you call the function fireworksTrigger in a main/setup run before the main loop starts

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the attention. I did the first change and now I have the same error that I`ve commented before: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null at fireworks.js:10. Also I did the change in the compiler. Now We have the button displayed, but we don`t have the js animation because of the error at line 10 fireworks.js

Comment: hmm i see. Usually that happens because whatever you are doing getContext on is null (or like when it tried to get the element using queryselector it got a null). You might want to check what exactly getcontext is being called on to make sure that whatever it is being called on isnt null. If youd like, you can post the code where it is doing the getcontext and i can try to help a bit more